# Weird bleak of color to materials in Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I have this weird colour bleak appearing to some meshes when I am in eevee preview or in render mode, when in cycles is perfectly fine.

Eevee view:
[image: This is the weird view in eevee]

Cycles view:
[image: this is in cycles]